# Returning cousins in Neo4j problem with WHERE

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have to make a Cypher query which is supposed to return cousins of a person (brothers, sisters, kids of brothers/sisters). It works almost fine, but the problem is that when I want to filter out the kids of the person (27003) `(precious)` writing `WHERE p2.personId<>27003` it also removes the mother of the person `(missing)`.

What have I done wrong here?

My cypher query:

```
MATCH (p: Person_kol)<-[]-(parent: Person_kol) WHERE p.idPerson=27003
WITH p,parent
MATCH (p3: Person_kol)<-[]-(p2: Person_kol)<-[]-(parent: Person_kol)
WHERE p2.idPerson<>27003
RETURN p,parent,p3,p2
```

My first match just returns the person of given id with his/her parent.

Second match just searches for brothers/sisters and his/her kids (I know that p2 also includes the person of id=27003 and his/her kids, that's why I want to filter them out, but my "WHERE" also removes the mother of the person (2nd picture)

Pictures:

1. (without WHERE clause)

[image: text]

2. (with WHERE)

[image: text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second match clause requires that `parent` has a grandchild `p3` whose parent is not `precious`. Since `missing` does not have any grandchildren in the first picture that meets that criteria, she is filtered out of the results.

If you want to include parents regardless of whether they have grandchildren who match the criteria, you could do an `optional match`.

```
MATCH (p: Person_kol)<--(parent: Person_kol) WHERE p.idPerson=27003
OPTIONAL MATCH (p3: Person_kol)<--(p2: Person_kol)<--(parent: Person_kol)
WHERE p2.idPerson<>27003
RETURN p,parent,p3,p2
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm a bit confused, because if I don't write WHERE idPerson<>27003, it returns the mother EVEN THOUGH I make my invalid MATCH, that you mentioned. So if I do my invalid match, which requires the parent to have any children, but I DO NOT write "WHERE", it returns the mother.

Comment: The documentation for OPTIONAL MATCH helps make sense of this. https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/optional-match/

With the WHERE idPerson<>27003 in the OPTIONAL MATCH, the mother is still returned because she matches the first MATCH clause. However, p3, and p2 are null because the pattern that involves the mother does not fit the optional match criteria.

Without the WHERE idPerson<>27003, you will get patterns for missing-precious-delicious and pregnant-precious-delicious that would not be there if you include the where clause.

Use table view in results to see this.

Comment: Oh, I see, so if I do WHERE, my precious is as "overwritten" as a "parent", but if I don't do WHERE, my "precious" is p2 right, and that's why mother is not returned?
I've got one more question- what should I do if I wanted NOT TO return "precious" (idPerson=27003) ' kids? (delcious,linear)?

Comment: Missing and pregnant are the two nodes that are matched as "parent" in the first pattern. Before filtering the second query, five nodes (including precious) are matched as p2 for pregnant, and precious is matched as the p2 for missing. If you include WHERE p2.idPerson <> 27003 in the OPTIONAL match clause, a filter is applied that drops any patterns where p2 is precious. If you don't return precious as p2, you should not return precious's kids as p3.